# TFS to GitHub Migration (Unable to push larger files into github that were actually removed from tfs repo before cloning using git tfs clone)

Tags: github, azure-devops, git-tfs

I am working on migrating the TFS repo with commit history to GitHub. I am using the tool https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs.

Till now I have migrated around 20 repo's using this tool. I am facing am issue while migrating files which are larger than 100mb(sqllite files).

Firstly I have identified files which are larger than 100mb and deleted them in TFS. Then I started using the command git tfs clone  . I am able to clone them but while I am merging them to GitHub (git push -u origin master) I am seeing this error (remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.)

The large files(>100mb) that push command is showing actually does not exist in the TFS repo/local folder

Can someone help me on how to untag or remove the traces of the files that actually does not exist in the local cloned folder, tfs repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried resolving this by this tool BFG Repo-Cleaner, this actually helped me to resolve the issue.

https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/

Comment: yes, when you deleted them in TFVC, they are still in the history, that should be clean uo

Comment: Thanks for your sharing. You could *mark your reply as an answer*.